# Can Microsoft accounts be created and managed via Active Directory / API?

Tags: active-directory

We are in the process of shifting over to Google (Apps) for Work. One of the cool things that this provides is 'Google Apps Directory Sync' https://support.google.com/a/answer/106368?hl=en which "automatically provision users, groups, and non-employee contacts based on the user data in your LDAP server, such as Microsoft Active Directory."

I am wondering if the same thing, or anything similar, is possible with Microsoft Accounts? If not via Active Directory, then via some other API?

Just to clarify, it may sound like I'm being vague when I say 'Microsoft Account', but I really do mean this. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/account/default.aspx 'Microsoft Account' is the new name for Windows Live IDs, and is "what you use for almost everything you do with Microsoft devices and services."

Any advice on how the creation and management of these Microsoft accounts could be automated is very much appreciated!

Comment: You can certainly sync and auto-create accounts used for Office 365.  these aren't the Live IDs though.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly possible... Kinda.
Microsoft produce a tool to sync AD accounts with office 365 (DirSync, which is discussed [here](http://blogs.office.com/2014/04/15/synchronizing-your-directory-with-office-365-is-easy/)), and tools to create accounts 'local' to O365 on a bulk basis (Powershell with a CSV file of users, discussed [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/08/04/use-powershell-to-create-bulk-users-for-office-365.aspx)). MS also allows you to [authenticate via ADFS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/04/28/how-to-install-adfs-2012-r2-for-office-365.aspx) in order to log in to O365 using accounts that are part of your local AD.

Strictly speaking these might not be "Microsoft Accounts" in the same way that an outlook.com account for 'sexy_bison75@outlook.com' might be, but these solutions allow corporate users to authenticate to use Microsoft cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You can certainly authenticate your Apps and everything using API's to the Microsoft Account, but to my knowledge there are no management API's.

However, companies do not really use Microsoft Accounts on a corporate base. If they need to sync accounts to Microsoft because they are using Office 365, then you sync the Accounts with your Office 365 Tenant Directory.

Also, Microsoft seems to support more and more of these so called "Organizational Accounts" in their own services. E.g. you can have Azure tied to an "Organizational Account" instead of a LiveId/Microsoft Account.